# Utilização de Tempo com EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Tenho uma classe com a seguinte propriedade.

```html
  public TimeSpan TempoIdeal { get; set; }

Estou atribuindo esta propriedade com 

TempoIdeal = new TimeSpan(days: 3, hours: 15, minutes:10, seconds: 0);
```

Ao tentar inserir recebo este erro Estouro

> SqlDbType.Time. O valor '3.03:03:00' está fora do intervalo. Ele deve
>   estar entre 00:00:00.0000000 e 23:59:59.9999999.

No SQL esta propriedade está sendo mapeada como Time(7);

Estou usando EF 6 com ASP.NET 4.52

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Berechit, o tipo `Time` no `Sql-Server` não foi projetado para armazenar intervalos de tempos, ou tempo relativo (como no seu exemplo: o produto demorou `3 dias, 15 horas e 10 minutos` para ser entregue), mas para armazenar um horario exato (como no seu exemplo: o produto será entregue as `15:10`).

Desta forma, não faz sentido o mesmo armazenar valores superiores à `23:59:59.9999999`. Então se realmente precisa armazenar valores superiores a``24 horas`, lhe aconselho à utilizar um campo`BigInt`no`Sql-Server` e fazer o seguinte mapeamento.

```
public Int64 TempoIdealTicks { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public TimeSpan TempoIdeal
{
    get { return TimeSpan.FromTicks(this.TempoIdealTicks); }
    set { this.TempoIdealTicks = value.Ticks; }
}
```